# Getting the value of SVG attributes in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am new to D3.js and am trying to build rectangles that represent all nodes from an XML file. So far so good but I want interactivity with each of the rectangles I draw and to be able to capture the nodes that have been touched for further processing. So let's say I click on a rectangle, I can make it react by doing an onclick event (like increasing the font size) but I can't seem to retrieve some of the info. I'd like to create an array with the text of each item that was clicked on.

Here's the code for one instance of the rectangle.

```
d3.select("#chart")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 600)
.attr("height", 2000)
.style("background", "#93A1A1")

d3.select("svg")
  .append("rect").attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 25)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("title", "resourceDef")
  .style("fill", "#CB4B19")

d3.select("svg")
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 55)
  .attr("y", 37)
  .attr("font-size", 11)
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .text("resourceDef")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    tempText = this.text;
    alert(tempText);
d3.select(this)
  .attr("font-size", 15)})  
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
  d3.select(this)
   .attr("font-size", 11)})
```

I can grab style info by using but not the title and I can't find that info anywhere. Thanks for your help, I know it's a long question with probably a simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a mouse over event on the rectangle DOM by doing something like this:

```
d3.select("svg")
    .append("rect").attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 25)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("title", "resourceDef")
    .style("fill", "#CB4B19")
    .on("click", function (d) {
    var t = d3.select(this).attr("title");
    //pushing the title into the array.
    clickedTitles.push(t);
    console.log(t);
});
```

You can get the attribute of a DOM(in your case tite) by doing something like this:

```
.on("click", function (d) {
    var t = d3.select(this).attr("title");
    clickedTitles.push(t);
    console.log(t)
})
```

You can store the clicked rectangles title in an array like this:

```
//create an array
var clickedTitles = [];
//in your click function push the title into the array
clickedTitles.push(t);

//use the clickedTitles where ever you need in the code
```

Full code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rn5L742w/).

Comment: This worked perfectly, exactly what I needed, I had the wrong syntax to get the title attribute. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, I voted up by I'm new here so it will only count when I get to reputation 15...